# Repeat image in body to every page in RDLC

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I want to repeat an image (behind the text) on evrey RDLC report page. Just like some letter heads.

Please make note that, The report is very simple and not include any complex data. It has only a single dynamic string list (coming from RIA Service) which is causing report to span over multiple pages.

[Sample report http://dc585.4shared.com/img/se3FRy9cce/s7/1461d2ba0e8/SS_online.jpg?async&rand=0.5226563094183803](http://dc585.4shared.com/img/se3FRy9cce/s7/1461d2ba0e8/SS_online.jpg?async&rand=0.5226563094183803)
grey rectangle on the right side is what i am looking for.

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to the Report you wish to add the repeating image.
- Select the body or the report item you want the image attached to.
- In the *properties window* expand the **BackgroundImage** section.
- **BackgroundRepeat** should have been exposed select the desired repeat style:  *Default, Repeat, RepeatX, RepeatY, Clip* or you may create an expression by selecting *...Expression*.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251715(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251715%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)